# Error when add "mpl-token-metadata", Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Tags: anchor, mpl-token-metadata

When I add "mpl-token-metadata" by Cargo then the transaction
response with error

> Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Before adding, the transaction is still running normally

File Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.28.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["metadata"] }
```

File lib.rs

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(bump_auth: u8)]
pub struct InitPool<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = 8 + 10 * std::mem::size_of::<Pool>())]
    pub pool: Box<Account<'info, Pool>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub admin: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut, seeds = [pool.key().as_ref()], bump = bump_auth)]
    pub pool_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

    // #[account(mut, seeds = [treasury.key().as_ref()], bump = bump_treasury)]
    // pub treasury_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

    // #[account(mut)]
    // pub treasury: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[program]
pub mod helloword {

    use super::*;

    pub fn init_pool(
        ctx: Context<InitPool>,
        bump_auth: u8,
        pool_config: PoolConfig,
        pool_treasury: Pubkey,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Init Pool");
        instructions::init_pool::handler(ctx, bump_auth, pool_config, pool_treasury)
    }
}
```

File test.ts

```
const tx = await program.methods
      .initPool(
        bumpAuth,
        {
          minStakingPeriodSec: new anchor.BN(100),
          // collection: new PublicKey("A9GvXJeWVHvuvqBvUsUtJtHQVdrYsFFFGaW6BbM8Y6Eh"),
        },
        treasury
      )
      .accounts({
        poolAuthority,
        pool: poolKeypair.publicKey,
        admin: adminKeypair.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        payer: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      })
      .signers([poolKeypair, adminKeypair])
      .rpc();
```

Help me, Please
Thanks

Comment: As @JonasH. already mentioned, the issue above is with the >= 1.16.0 solana version and downgrading should fix it. Here's the relevant gh [issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960). Can you specify your anchor version? Also, try deleting cargo.lock and building again

Answer (score 2):

can you please send the command with

```
.rpc({
      skipPreflight: true,
    });
```

and the paste the signature into https://explorer.solana.com/

This should show you the proper on chain error.

I guess since it was working before that you updated the cli tools to 1.16.1
which has a problem with too big transaction data currently.

If so downgrading your cli version could fix it.

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.14.18/install)"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried using "skipPreflight":true,
and i tried on devnet but still error
here is my transaction https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5ZGQZW5p5q69KcEsfD8fakM59H1ooiY1vdqbzwps2YoRTXzp5CzJFgwWecpv41Xky54He5RhCKZcHVzzsamgsHSa?cluster=devnet

Comment: Yeah this is axactly the error happening when using the newest cli version, please try downgrade to 1.14.18 with the command i posted above, then build and deploy again, that should fix it.

Comment: I got it, but when I downgrade to 1.14.18 then I have new error when I call comand "anchor build", with error "package `hashbrown v0.14.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.64.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev"
while I installed Rustc version "rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)"

Comment: Oh then maybe mpl-token-metadata needs an update. Currently don't know the solution. :-/ Is using anchor and spl 27 an option?